# How do you test for a NULL string  field in the Field Calculator with Python?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, field-calculator

I am trying to perform an operation on a string field with a condition that it contains data. Referencing `None` with Python does not appear to work when the field is nullable and contains `<Null>` for its data. Am I missing something? I have tried `len()` and `"<Null>"` and `"Null"` as well. What do?

The code, for kicks:

```
def apt(addr,aptnum):
    if aptnum != None:
        a = addr.split(aptnum,1)[-1]
        return a
    else:
        return addr
```

Update: It would appear that my problem is that field calculations are not processing on any rows where a `null` column is tested. That is outside the scope of this question, however, so I will leave it for the time being.

Comment: Have you compared it to the null string ""?

Comment: Are you on the latest service pack?

Comment: @Jason Scheirer No, we have not upgraded to SP2 yet.

Comment: @Nathanus Ok, I just recently did a bunch of fixes related to `NULL`s in field calculator and I'm pretty sure they made it into SP2.

Comment: I have the same problem.
I am trying to remplace <Null> in a field with 0. I add another field and then I use the codeblock. But nothing is happend. codeblock: """def reclass ( Neighbours2): if Neighbours2 == None: return 0""" Expression: "reclass (!Neighbours2!)"
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what you are querying (eg shapefile, geodatabase), but have a look at
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002t000000.htm
specifically the section on "The NULL keyword"

EDIT
Adding a field to a shapefile, using the field calculator on this field, then using the following as the code block (Python parser)

```
def TestForNull(a_field):
  if not a_field:
   return "is null"
```

with 
TestForNull(!YourFieldNameHere!)
in the expression line, results in "is null" being added to the field.  You will of course have to modify to suit your purposes.

Comment: This works in the field calculator Codeblock? I'm a bit lost as to how this will help me out.

Comment: did you try it? ie
"myFieldNameHere" IS NULL
where of course the field is your field.  In theory, it should select the records with Null values.  I don't have any shapefiles that have null records, so you will have to test it on your own data.  Check the other options if you don't want the null records.

Comment: SQL syntax does not work on the Field Calculator dialog (unless you are using a cursor in the code block which is not a very good idea).

Comment: @blah Dan Patternson is not using SQL syntax.  His solution is pure Python.

Comment: This works well enough. Apparently my problem is that the field itself is not responding to field calculations. Joy.

Comment: @whuber I think we must have been looking at different things, the current edit is Python but previously I think there was some confusion between whether we were talking about the Field Calculator (Python) or Select by Attributes (SQL) dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

Try just

`if aptnum:`

This tests for both null and zero-length strings.

Answer (score 1):

or you could use
`if aptnum is None:`

Answer (score 1):

This answer from PolyGeo worked for me:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/81155/44980

.strip() removes all whitespace characters

```
def TestForNull(Field1):
  if Field1.strip() == "":
    return 'is null'
  else:
    return 'not null'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I spent a lot of time figuring out that an empty text field is actually " " instead of "".

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the codeblock as apt(!addr!,str(!aptnum!)).