# Replace Null Values Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, field-calculator

I am using ArcGIS 10 and have a polygon shapefile in which many of the numeric fields are Null.

The polygon shapefile in question is produced by joining a polygon shapefile with a point shapefile and the "Count_" field contains the count of how many points fall inside the polygon. I would like to convert these Nulls to 0. So I have used two scripts in Field Calculator(Python). Both of the scripts execute successfully but produce no results i.e. the null values are not replaced. The two scripts are as follows:

```
def rep_null(count):
  if count is None:
    return 0
  else:
    return count
```

and

```
def rep_null(count):
  out=0
  if count>=1:
    out=count
  return out
```

What is the way out?

Comment: I had a similar question to yours before, see link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29146/update-null-values-mdb-table

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why is it required to convert it to string though!