# Parse multiple field in field calculator using python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes, python-parser

I'm trying to fill a blank field depending on the contents of three other fields using python in the field calculator.

Sample code is something like:

```
def getClass(Text1,Text2,Text3):
  if Text1 is None:
    return Text2
  elif Text2 is None:
    return Text3      
  else:
    return Text1
```

I can retrieve the value of the first field but never the 2nd two. I know this isn't the right way but I can't figure out the nesting levels... Any ideas?

UPDATE: Fixed by stripping out the white space. Credit to this post [Using Calculate Field tool to calculate on null fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81143/calculate-field-tool-to-calculate-on-null-fields/81155#81155)

```
def getClass(Text1,Text2,Text3):
  if Text1.strip():
    x = Text1
  elif Text2.strip():
    x = Text2    
  elif Text3.strip():
    x = Text3
  else:
    x = "NA";
  return x
```

Comment: Are the Text fields actually Null, or just empty, i.e. '' ?

Comment: Text fields are empty ''

Answer (score 1):

Use the "not equal" operator for the field calculator.

```
def getClass(Text1,Text2,Text3):
  if Text1 != None:
    return Text1
  elif Text2 != None:
    return Text2      
  elif Text3 != None:
    return Text3
  else:
    return None;
```

You may also want to account for the possibility that none of the input fields have a value, as seen in the code snippet I posted.

Also, checkout this post about the difference between using the "is" operator versus "==":

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: @recurvata brings up a good point in the comment above.  If you need to account for empty strings in place of <Null>,  you could modify the boolean expressions like so --->  if Text1 != None and Text1 != "":

Comment: A simpler way would just be `if Text1:` -- Both `None` and empty strings `''` are false-y values in Python.

Comment: I've tried all of the options mentioned and they return `Text1` but not `Text2` or `Text3`. This is the same whether I use `None` or `''` and `!=` or `if Text1:`. Is this a job that field calculator can't handle and should I switch to arcpy instead?

Comment: Can't tell if you mean '' above or ' ' (an empty space) in your comment above. Empty space is likely incorrect. If no values are Null, testing for None won't help. '' or ' ' will always return Text1 in your code above, since '' and ' ' both != None; that is, your first test is always True, thereby returning Text1. Same with if Text1:

Comment: Fixed. Using this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81143/calculate-field-tool-to-calculate-on-null-fields/81155#81155

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're passing the other fields in the function call at the bottom.  `getClass(!Field1!, !Field2, !Field3!)`